# Bootstrap starter template collapsed menu doesn't highlight properly

Tags: templates, twitter-bootstrap

Just displaying the url `http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html#` correctly but I don't understand (ok I'm starting with Bootstrap) when I reduce the browser window size, I get the menu button, the menu is well displayed but only the Home option is highlited correctly when hovering on it. I put my js at the end of the body and jquery before bootstrap.js.
It is the same thing with Firefox or Chrome and with Internet Explorer 10 the demo is not responsive the menu button doesn't appear the nav stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your point that the links don't change on hover for screens < 980px wide, I'm not sure if this behaviour intentional or not, but it's coming from line 1028 of bootstrap-responsive.css

If you want the link colors to change on hover, edit the styling as below to force the color as #fff:

```
.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover, .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:focus {
background-color: #111;
color: #fff;
}
```

The color for the home link is a special case and is changing because it has inherited the styling of the active class (from line 4825 of bootstrap.css)

I don't have an IE10 to look into your other question.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks,your answer allowed me to dig a little bit in the css file.
It works so I will see where I will put the css mod (not really fond of modifyin the bootastrap file..°. For the Internet explorer case It was badly my setup which was blocking the script......

Comment: That's great, I'm pleased it was helpful.